# Fixed QGIS layer symbol size in layer legend

Tags: qgis, layers, symbology

When a layer symbol is defined with map units or "meters at scale" unit, it is sometimes shown in the legend at a very small scale, preventing to see the details. Or if we zoom in the map, the legend will be shown in a very large scale, see image below (reference https://issues.qgis.org/issues/8884 )

Is there a way I can keep the layer symbol scalable in the map, but have fixed size for the layer symbol legend?

[image]

Comment: I think that bug was solved in the stable versions of QGIS. Upgrade to the latest stable versions: Current Release: 3.4.3, Long Term Release: 2.18.27.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca I just downloaded 3.4.4 and unfortunately I still see the same behavior..

Comment: Symbology in the layer panel in QGIS 3.4.4 is size fixed, I can't reproduce your issue here. Please add a new question for that version, please add the more detailed process to reproduce the issue. Include if you are installing from stand-alone or network installer. And a screenshot of the layer symbology properties.

Comment: Same problem occured on the QGIS 3.10 QGIS version 3.10.0-A Coruna QGIS code revision 6c816b4204

Answer (score 3):

In 3.14, the max symbol size in the legend for "map units" / "meters at scale" seems to be fixed. The legend updates, however, are delayed which means that the legend does not update immediately when the map is redrawn after zooming:

[image]

Comment: I observe that the symbology in the layer panel updates when toggling 'show feature count', still in 3.16

Answer (score 0):

I still have the same Issue in  QGIS 3.22.8.
As fas as I observed, this only happens when i classify multiple symbols within a single shapefile-layer.
When I change the setting from 'Map Units' to 'meters in scale'the symbols in my layerpanel appear in normal size again, but the symbology is still different from the one I set.
I hope this helps to resolve the Issue.

[image: Symbology in Layer Panel different than in Layer Style Panel]

[image: Set to map units]

[image: Set to meters at Scale]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/243519)